# Xoring in constant time in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bitwise

I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670379/1065835) and [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670524/1065835) and decided to support negative numbers. While testing, I noticed that the solution didn't handle the case with one number in the given range. A quick way to fix it was just adding

```
else if (a == b) {
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have:

```
package xor;

public class Xor {

    public static int getXorNeg(int x) {
        if (x > 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("x cannot be positive");
        }
        int res[] = { 0, x, 1, x - 1 };
        return res[-x % 4];
    }

    public static int getXorPos(int a) {
        if (a < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a cannot be negative");
        }
        int[] res = { a, 1, a + 1, 0 };
        return res[a % 4];
    }

    public static int getXor(int a, int b) {
        if (a > b) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a must be less than or equals to b");
        } else if (a == b) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (b < 0) { // both a and b are negative
            return getXorNeg(a) ^ getXorNeg(b + 1);
        } else if (a > 0) { // both a and b are positive
            return getXorPos(b) ^ getXorPos(a - 1);
        } else { // a is negative, and b is positive
            return getXorNeg(a) ^ getXorPos(b);
        }
    }

    public static int getXorInLinearTime(int a, int b) {
        if (a > b) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a must be less than or equals to b");
        } else if (a == b) {
            return 0;
        }
        int res = a;
        for (int i = a + 1; i <= b; i++) {
            res ^= i;
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

**Testing.**

```
package xor;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XorTest {

    @Test
    public void xorNegModZero() {
        int value = -84;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(value, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorNeg(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorNegModOne() {
        int value = -145;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(value, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorNeg(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorNegModTwo() {
        int value = -42;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(value, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorNeg(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorNegModThree() {
        int value = -43;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(value, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorNeg(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorPosModZero() {
        int value = 84;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(0, value);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorPos(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorPosModOne() {
        int value = 145;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(0, value);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorPos(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorPosModTwo() {
        int value = 42;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(0, value);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorPos(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorPosModThree() {
        int value = 47;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(0, value);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXorPos(value));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorLeftAndRightPositive() {
        int from = 47;
        int to = 67;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(from, to);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXor(from, to));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorLeftAndRightNegative() {
        int from = -67;
        int to = -47;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(from, to);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXor(from, to));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorEquals() {
        int from = -67;
        int to = -67;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(from, to);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXor(from, to));
    }

    @Test
    public void xorLeftNegativeAndRightPositive() {
        int from = -47;
        int to = 67;
        int res = Xor.getXorInLinearTime(from, to);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, Xor.getXor(from, to));
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void xorPosWithNegative() {
        Xor.getXorPos(-1);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void xorNegWithPositive() {
        Xor.getXorNeg(90);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void xorInvalidRange() {
        Xor.getXor(10, 9);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The big issue that strikes me is documentation. Looking at the code, I have very little idea of what it's supposed to do, and even less idea of whether or not it's correct.

What do `a` and `b` mean? In particular, what is the range of numbers that are xored? Without looking at `getXorInLinearTime` I would guess that it's from `a` inclusive to `b` exclusive, but looking at `getXorInLinearTime` that seems to be wrong.

What do `getXorNeg` and `getXorPos` do? They're public, so presumably they're intended to be useful quite apart from `getXor`, but I don't see for what.

Clever code needs good commenting. The trick used by `getXor` is definitely clever enough that it requires an explanation of what's going on, and really I would like to see a formal proof of correctness.

Are both `getXorNeg` and `getXorPos` required? They seem to be treated differently (both negative => `getXorNeg(a) ^ getXorNeg(b + 1)` but both positive => `getXorPos(a - 1) ^ getXorPos(b)`), suggesting that there's an out-by-one error in the implementation of one of them, and I suspect (although I haven't tested it) that `getXorPos` would work for negative numbers too if the `%` were replaced by a true modulus operation (i.e. in this special case `& 3` instead of `% 4`).

Why is `getXorInLinearTime` in the public interface of the implementation class? Its only purpose would seem to be for testing the efficient `getXor`, so in my opinion it belongs in the test class.

---

Addendum: I think that `getXorInLinearTime` must be incorrect. If `a < b` it xors the numbers from `a` inclusive to `b` inclusive, but if `a == b` it xors the numbers from `a` inclusive to `b` exclusive (or some other empty set). If it's intended always to xor from `a` inclusive to `b` inclusive then `a == b` doesn't need a special case, and should always return `a`.

Comment: If I use `& 3` instead of `a % 4`  in `getXorPos`, it won't work for negative numbers. With positive numbers there is one pattern: 0^1^2^3 = 0, 4^5^6^7=0, and so on. With negative numbers the pattern is a different: -1^-2^-3^-4=0. As far as I understand, `a &3` is the same as `a % 4`, but it returns a positive result when `a` is negative. So given a positive number `a` such that `a % 4 == 0`, the result of xoring from 0 to `a` (inclusive) the number itself. But given a negative number `a` such that `a % 4 == 0`, the result is 0.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev, yes, now that I've tested it I see the problem. It's still relatively simple to fix: `if (x < 0) x--; int[] res = { x, 1, x + 1, 0 }; return res[x & 3];`. Just requires a bit more commenting to explain the `if (x < 0) x--;`.